# User Login using XCode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have two view controllers (view1 and view2(say)). In view1 I've textfields for entering Username and Password, and a Login button. On pressing Login, the user should be able to push to view2(if the username and password are verified from the database). I've added the following method, which is called when Login is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender
{      const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiary) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT *FROM USERDETAIL"];
         const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary, 
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                Gusr = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                Gpass = [[NSString alloc]
                         initWithUTF8String:
                         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                NSLog(@"%@  %@",Gusr,Gpass);
                NSLog(@"%@  %@",mUserName.text,mPassword.text);
                if (!([mUserName.text isEqualToString:Gusr] && [mPassword.text isEqualToString:Gpass])){

                    NSLog(@"Invalid credentials");
                    mUserName.text = @"";
                    mPassword.text = @"";
                    //  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
                }else {

                }

            }



        }   
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }     
    sqlite3_close(mDiary);  
}
```

The problem is that the user is able to login with any credentials. Gusr and Gpass are getting printed in log. I should also probably metion here that view1 and view2 have the same custom class.(I'm using storyboard)

OK adding this to the else part makes it work:

```
VIewControllerName *obj = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_storyBoardId"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Thanks to Kumar.. :)

Comment: print username and password also and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done that. And both are getting printed.

Comment: not Gusr, Gpass print mUserName.text,mPassword.text values.

Comment: I was referring to that only.. sorry I forgot to edit the code here. Both mUserName.text and mPassword.text are getting printed correctly in the log

Comment: I've a push segue from Login button to view2. I suppose I need it to work based on the condition that if the username and password are valid then push to view2 else not. How can I do that? Because otherwise, it is just pushing to view2 anyway, regardless of what is being entered as username and password.

Comment: using UINavigationController..? , what exactly you need here?

Comment: yes the view controllers are embedded in navigation controller. view1 is the root view controller. In the stroryboard Triggered segues  action I have specified Push and in Sent Events- Touch Up Inside I've added the method clickButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this .:

```
if ([mUserName.text isEqualToString:Gusr] && [mPassword.text isEqualToString:Gpass]){


 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
 VIewControllerName *obj = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_storyBoardId"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES]; // This is using by navigation controller , Are You using it?



                }else {

                    NSLog(@"Invalid credentials");
                    mUserName.text = @"";
                    mPassword.text = @"";
                }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this, but is throwing the following exception:Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Guest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/CCEB4AAE-A6D6-4C2E-A13D-BCF2695D2786/SmartDiary.app> (loaded)' I removed the push segue from the storyboard, then it worked fine for invalid credentials. This exception oviously comes when the credentials are correct.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Don't put with the extension . .just put "  MainStoryboard_iPhone "

Comment: thanks.. :) I've edited it in a different way though and it works.. Please tell me if that is appropriate

Comment: yes No problem with that .. for some situation You need to identify the storybord also .. for single .. this is enough ...